# How to create binary column base on values in other column and drop duplicates in SAS Enterprise Guide 4GL / PROC SQL?

Tags: sas, proc-sql, enterprise-guide

I have table in SAS Enterprise Guide like below:

- ID - numeric
- COL1 - numeric

| ID | COL1 |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 123 | 0 |
| 123 | 0 |
| 444 | 1 |
| 444 | 0 |
| 778 | 0 |

And I need to aggregate above table and create column 'TARGET':

- `TARGET = 1 for these IDs which at least once have '1' in the column 'COL1'`
- `TARGET = 0 for these IDs which have never had a '1' in the column 'COL1'`

`Moreover I need to delete duplicates in ID`, so as a result i need something like below :

| ID | TARGET |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 -> `had '1' at least once in COL1` |
| 444 | 1 -> `had '1' at least once in COL1` |
| 778 | 0 -> `never had '1' in COL1` |

How can I do that in SAS Enterprise Guide in normal SAS code or in PROC SQL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is equivalent to taking the maximum value of the column for each ID.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select ID, max(col1) as Target
from have
group by ID;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DOW loop over the group, computing a repeated OR result.

Example:

```
data want;
  do until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    if not target then 
      target = target or col1;
  end;
run;
```